# How to use fetch to post some data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, get, fetch-api

I just wanted to know if there's anyway I can post data using fetch API from MoviesDB. I was able to post the info to the console. But now I would like to actually render in on my React Page. Here is my code below. Any help is appreciated.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';            

class Home extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      posts:{}
    }
    
  }

  getPost = () => {
    return fetch("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=54a83919a7f93d82a8b8bdd417544d6f")
  .then(res=>res.json())
  .then(posts => console.log(posts))
  }
      
render() {
  
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <div className="headings">
      <img className="LOGO" src="https://www.moonlight.com.au/wp-content/themes/moonlight-2016/dist/images/moonlight-logo.png" alt="back"/>
      <input className="input"
        placeholder="Enter a movie title" />
        <button onClick={this.getPost}>Get post</button>
        <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state.posts)}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
    }
}
    
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your render method you're using `this.state.posts` but you're not updating it anywhere.

Replace `.then(posts => console.log(posts))` with `.then(posts => this.setState({ posts }))`.